# How to add an image to javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I cannot seem to find how to add an image to Javascript. I'm currently creating an animation and all I want to do is at the start of the animation I was going to add 4 numbers that count down from 4 in time to music.

I was going to make each number fly off the side of each corner of the page to indicate the countdown, but I can't seem to insert any of my images.

I've tried using code I've found online, but nothing seems to work.

Can someone help give me the exact code I'd need to put an image into my Javascript?

My Code looks something like this.

```
window.onload= function (){

var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 800, 600);

var backGround = paper.rect(0,0,800,600);

backGround.attr({ fill: "black"});

/* Comment - Add your code here*/

var ball = paper.circle(40,270,10);
var paddleleft = paper.rect(10, 230, 15, 100);
var paddleright = paper.rect(775, 230, 15, 100);
var line = paper.rect(400, 0, 5, 600);

ball.attr({ fill: "white"});
paddleleft.attr({ fill: "white"});
paddleright.attr({ fill: "white"});
line.attr({ fill: "white"});

function bounce_drop1() {

ball.animate({cy: 50 , cx: 750}, 500, 'ease-in', bounce_up1);

}
function bounce_up1() {

ball.animate({cy: 50, cx: 750}, 500, 'ease-out', bounce_drop2);
}

bounce_drop1();

function bounce_drop2() {

ball.animate({cy: 570 , cx: 400}, 500, 'ease-in', bounce_up2);

}
function bounce_up2() {

ball.animate({cy: 50, cx: 50}, 500, 'ease-out', bounce_drop1);
}

};
```

I'm not sure where exactly the put the image, but following the posts below I've attempted this.

```
var imgSrc = "http://www.pnglogo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/4-Number-Clipart-PNG-02202.png";
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgSrc;

document.getElementById('mygallery').appendChild(img);
```

But it's not doing anything, am I meant to state the image as a variable?

Sorry I'm new to using Javascript and I apparently need "imported bitmap images" into my animation.

Comment: What is "putting an image into JavaScript"?

Comment: You have to provide more information. JavaScript itself doesn't have anything to do with images, so it's unclear what "how to add an image to Javascript" means. You could as well be asking "how to add an elephant to JavaScript".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have code that doesn't work, post it as a *reduced* example that *fully* replicates the issue. Asking for the exact code just isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

So I´m guessing you have some sort of HTML file which loads up your javascript. To get an image into that you will need to:

1. create a new HTML node of the type `<img />`
2. This node will need `src` attribute to define where the image is coming from (maybe from your local file system or hosted anywhere in the web).
3. After you created the HTML node you need to append it to an already existing DOM-Node to actually "show up".
4. When this is all done you should have your image nodes and can animate/manipulate them anyway you want e.g. with CSS or JavaScript

Code might look something like this:

```
var img = document.createElement('img);
img.src = 'http://somelinktoanimage';

var parentNode = document.getElementById('parentNodeId');
parentNode.appendChild(img);
```

This is a VERY basic example and with your information given I´m not really sure if it applies to your use case.

Also I recommend reading up on some basic stuff:

[Web technology for developers MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web)

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple to create and add an image on the DOM.

create image object and add it to the DOM:

```
var imgSrc = "http://fabricjs.com//assets/pug_small.jpg";
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgSrc;

document.getElementById('mygallery').appendChild(img);
```

live jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/p3h67n1u/

hope helps ,good luck.

Comment: Would I have to put any code to show the image in the animation? I've copied your code and replaced the imgSrc with my own image, but when I refresh the page I don't see any image. Am I supposed to add another variable that shows the image, along with the size?

Comment: 1. you create the variables with your image urls. 2. you create the image objects.  3. you show them on the DOM . these are the steps.
On jsfiddle i show that functionaity. if you want to add animation to your code you need css transition, that is something that is not on your question. But it is better to make a url with your code on jsfiddle, to examine it closer.